# lower vs islower methods in if statements

Tags: python

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
            if letter.isupper():
                translation = translation + "Q"
            else:
                translation = translation + "q"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print(translate(input("Enter phrase to translate: ")))
```

Hi, I'm new to Python and this is my first post here. I'm following a Python tutorial and I'm a little confused, this code executes fine, I'm just wondering why the following code works:

```
if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "Q"
```

If letter.lower converts each letter in sequence to a lower case, how could the next if statement return anything for letter.isupper?

If the phrase is "AaAa", wouldn't letter.lower() convert that to aaaa first, before checking the letter.isupper, meaning nothing could be isupper? Yet, it still works, and AaAa returns QqQq.

Also, is my formatting correct for posting the code on here? I just pasted it and clicked the bracket button.

Thanks

Comment: ```if letter.lower() in "aeiou:"``` is looking for vowels, and only returns True or False.  you could sub that statement out with ```if letter in "aeiouAEIOU:"```

Comment: As long as you aren't _assigning_ `letter.lower()` to `letter` you're fine

Comment: `letter.lower()` returns a new string, and doesn't modify the string-inplace. Strings are immutable in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The `lower` method'1 only *returns* a lowercase letter (or the original string if there is no lowercase version); it does not change `letter` itself.

```
>>> letter = 'A'
>>> letter
'A'
>>> letter.lower()
'a'
>>> letter
'A"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

lower() will return the lowercase character and you are checking if its a vowel. The letter itself is not changed e.g. A will remain as A

```
if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
```

The next line you are checking if its in upper case using isupper to add uppercase Q else lowercase q

```
if letter.isupper():
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused .I will make you very clear with your codes.

Please follow the steps below:-

1.your code:

```
    if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
        if letter.isupper():
            translation=translation + "Q"
        else:
            translation=translation + "q"
```

In the first line of above code ,first of all you converted the letter(it can be in uppercase or lowercase) to lowercase.Then you checked that if it is in "aeiou" or not ,if the letter is there in "aeiou" then next if statement will get executed.

2. Now plese note that the letter you converted in the first line to lowercase remains in lowercase upto the execution of first line only,it means that the role of original case of the letter(case of letter while inputting it ) comes in account from second line,it also mean that the isupper() function do not change the case of the letter permanently.

3.According to your input "AaAa".First the letter 'A' will get converted into 'a' and as 
 'a' is there in "aeiou" control of program will go to second 'if' statement and there your letter is "A"(original case while input) so you get 'Q' as the result of 3rd statement and  then this process continues for all letter("AaAa") and your output is "QqQq".

For more clarification of your doubt please refer to the code below and you will never stuck in this problem anymore:-

```
s="AaAa"
for letter in s:
    print(letter.lower())
    print(letter)
```

output:

a

A

a

a

a

A

a

a

ya you are correct with your formatting of code .You can post your question in a more better way but the way you have posted is also fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help